# hide menu after clicking (fade out)

Tags: javascript, html, css

this simple html css menu.
now it working fine for page re-direction(href).

but **i want hide after when click on it.**

i just call on function when click on it which will call ajax request

http://jsfiddle.net/5TBFr/ code is here in link

[image: here is image snap]

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, I got lost after second line :(

Comment: It works as expected in Mozilla Firefox. Are you trying in some other browser.

Comment: It closes after clicking on Google Chrome too...

Comment: Also working on Explorer

Comment: Lol if it works on explorer then thats it! It will work, even on mars! What ever browser they use up there :)

Comment: It works because jsFiddle makes a redirect and rerenders the page. I think he wants to fadeOut the submenu and add dynamic content with javascript then.

Comment: @Craftero : now refer (sorry)

Comment: @Murtaza : because it refresh the current page and load again

Comment: For fades and event cancelling, your best best is JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supose this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/5TBFr/26/

I've added a click event on the a elements, and I'm returning false, so the request is stopped. You can add your ajax request there. I made a little work around, moving the "ul" element so the mouse leaves it and hides, then I'm moving it back to it's initial position.

Comment: `.closest('ul')` might be better than `parent().parent()`.

Comment: @gabitzish : it is not working when after hide. next time it will not appear(not fade-in).

Comment: The link in the answer is outdated. Here is one that works without refresh http://jsfiddle.net/5TBFr/26/

Comment: @gabitzish : your solution is right but make problem ... move hole gui right and left :( any other solution or any other menu... ?? one think keep in mind my page never refresh..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if I understood you, for what you want you are going to need jQuery, why? Because javascript doesn't know what CSS properties are affecting to an specific element.

Second, the way you are using CSS is not the correct one, you are mixing desing and functionality and for the easiest task like this one you will encounter problems like this one. CSS is not intended to show or hide menus even if you can, CSS is to style things even dinamically but when the user interaction gets involved you are screwed. So be careful :P

In jQuery should be something like this:

```
$(document)​.ready(function()
{
    $('ul').on('click', 'li a', function()
    {
        $(this.parentElement.parentElement).hide();
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TBFr/25/

Comment: Your jsFiddle works because you keep doing the request. You must return false at click. Returning false would work for you only once, because it hidden ul element will never appear again.

Comment: "Because javascript doesn't know what CSS properties are affecting to an specific element." Of course it does. Since jQuery is JavaScript, anything jQuery can do, JavaScript can do.

Comment: @j08691 sure, jQuery is javascript, but I don't wanna know what internally does jQuery to retrieve in a easy fancy list all the css properties are directly affecting a DOM element. If you know please would be appreciated

Comment: @gabitzish If I readed correctly Ankur does not want to prevent the default bheaviour, but hide the menu when the user clicks on it.

Comment: Refreshing the page already hides the menu ... so, I see no difference between your result and his.

Comment: @gabitzish Me neither, but we don't know know why he wants that, may be he has a reason to ask for this. If he speaks and explains may be we could be more helpful

Comment: @DavidDiez : i am using **href="#"** page never reload.. here http://jsfiddle.net/5TBFr/25/ page will refreshed so way element reload and menu again appear. but in **href="#"** page never reload so menu is hide never appear for next time.

Comment: You should use divs for that instead of anchors with null hrefs